hibernate 6 hql to native sql generation require old version alias
Hi I am working on migrating an old project to hibernate 6, currently in hibernate 5.
The problem is that there is a custom solution that relies on the old way Hibernate 5 generated native SQL. Pasing the SQL and making transformations(mainly column aliases) to it(renaming, removing, adding stuff).
Is there any way to reenable SQL generation the old way, or to get the old SQL generation ported? (even better if it can be ported in a contained manner) or any other sugestions?
Migrating the code that relies on this "tricks" is a non trivial amount that could take months to port.
Any sugestions would be grately welcome.
